# Is there a better way to split the reducers to smaller pieces?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to have one object in store with smaller objects inside like this in the example. But I have a large number of reducers which I want to plit to smaller pieces.
Currently I thinking about the following solution.

```
// Final Redux store that I want to have
largeObj: {
  someValue: 'Some value'
  smallObjA: {...}, 
  smallObjB: {...}
}
```

```
// myReducer.js
import { initialState: initialStateA, reducersA } from './reducersA.js';
import { initialState: initialStateB, reducersB } from './reducersB.js';

const initialState = {
  someVal: '',
  smallObjA: initialStateA,
  smallObjB: initialStateB
}

export const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'myState',
  reducers: {
    updateSomeVal: (state, action) => state.someVal = action.payload;
    ...reducersA,
    ...reducersB
  }
});
```

```
// reducersA.js
export const initialState = {...};

export const reducersA = {
  reducer1: (state, action) => {...},
  reducer2: (state, action) => {...},
  .....
  reducerN: (state, action) => {...},
};
```

```
// reducersB.js
export const initialState = {...};

export const reducersB = {
  reducer1: (state, action) => {...},
  reducer2: (state, action) => {...},
  .....
  reducerN: (state, action) => {...},
};
```

Can you please suggest better solution to solve that?

PS: not sure how it can be solved with combineReducers because of 'someVal' which should be on the main object.

Answer (score 0):

you could create two extra slices, `smallObjASlice` and `smallObjBSlice` and do something like

```js
export const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'myState',
  reducers: {
    updateSomeVal: (state, action) => state.someVal = action.payload;
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addMatcher(
      () => true, // do this for all actions!
      (state, action) => {
        state.smallObjA = smallObjASlice.reducer(state, action);
        state.smallObjB = smallObjBSlice.reducer(state, action);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: This line "state.smallObjA = smallObjASlice.reducer(state, action);" leads to the following error "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at findNonSerializableValue (redux-toolkit.esm.js:327)", is it possible that what I am trying to do is a bad practice?

Comment: Not really, just a bit uncommon. Is your child state somehow referencing a parent state and creating a circle that way?